# Compiling and executing Redis ziplist.c

Tags: c, redis

How do I compile and execute [Redis ziplist.c](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/2.6/src/ziplist.c) as individual executable ?

I want to execute ziplist.c main function ONLY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following command:

```
gcc -std=c99 -O2 -DZIPLIST_TEST_MAIN ziplist.c zmalloc.c util.c sds.c adlist.c
```

Note: it will use the default system allocator.

Comment: many thanks Didier :) i'll give default system allocator a go, and then will try jemalloc.